# Remove Spotify icon from panel?

Tags: spotify

I installed Spotify (folowing the instuctions here: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu) 
For some reason it adds an ugly low res icon/item to the menu bar that does not fit the theme at all. I tried to search the options for an option to remove it, but I could not find any.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUJwv.png

So my question is, if there is some tool or something I could use to remove items from the menu bar? Or just a way to hide this ugly green icon

Answer (score -1):

You can click on the Spotify icon and click quit or Go into Spotify > Prefs > Show/Hide Panel Icon

Comment: There is no such thing that i can find, if there is could you maybe screenshot it to show it?